# Textured model export - result doesn't contain the textures

Tags: texturing, materials, export, .fbx

Not a Blender pro here. I have this dummy character ready for export. It has a shape and a set of UVs (head, body, legs, eyes); the packed .blend file [can be downloaded here](https://new.dercetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/girl.zip). It's about 4MB.

It's basic, but it helps to test each step until it's rigged, animated and imported in Unreal:

[image: the basics]

I must export this character and make sure the file contains the texture data.

**I first tried using the .fbx format**

See my export settings using the "copy" and "embed texture" checkbox:

[image: the fbx settings using the "copy" and "embed texture" checkbox]

A small .fbx is generated (+/- 500kB) and no materials are copied in the dest folder.

As I import this in, say, Mixamo, the character appears solid white instead of being textured. I've used Mixamo in the past and know for sure it displays the texture if it's properly packaged:

[image]

Of course, I'm missing something. But I doubt it's in my way of exporting since I get the same result with .obj exports.

**I then tried with the .obj format**

I see "write materials" is checked by default and I've checked "material groups", just in case it changes anything:

[image]

Ok. I'm stuck here and I can't find why. I'm looking in the area of materials, textures, but this trial & error is not going anywhere so far.

I thank in advance anyone who's read my question :-)

Comment: Unpack the blend file to get the textures in image format, then create the material in the game engine.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541